# is it possible to auto ignore the struct fields when using Deserialize

Tags: rust, serde

I am using rust rocket as the http server side. On the server side, I define a rust struct like this to receive the data from client side:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct PlayRecordRequest {
    pub id: i64,
    pub title: String,
    pub url: String,
    pub mvId: i64,
    pub album: MusicAlbum,
    pub artist: Vec<Artist>,
}
```

and recieve in the http controller like this:

```
#[post("/user/v1/save-play-record", data = "<record>")]
pub fn save_play_record<'r>(
    record: Json<PlayRecordRequest>,
) -> content::Json<String> {
    info!("save play record,title:{}",record.title);
    save_play_record_impl(record);
    let res = ApiResponse {
        result: "ok".to_string(),
        ..Default::default()
    };
    let result_json = serde_json::to_string(&res).unwrap();
    return content::Json(result_json);
}
```

the problem is that when the client side did not have some fields, the code run into error. is it possible to auto fit the field for Deserialize, if the client have the field, Deserialize it normally, if the client did not contains some fields, just ignore it and do not run into error. I read the official document of serde and find the `skip` [annotation](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#skip).  But the annotation just use to mark the field should be ignored, what I want is that the struct could auto fit all field exists or not. is it possible to do like this?

Comment: I think you are looking for `#[serde(default)]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this.

First is with options. Options imply that the data may or may not exist. If the data is `null` or missing it convert to an `Option::none` value. You can preserve the lack of data on serialization if you add `#[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]`

Second option is to apply defaults to the value if the data is missing. Although from your use case this doesn't seem to be ideal.

Here is a code snippet of the two cases that you can run on https://play.rust-lang.org/:

```
use::serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct Foo {
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub bar: Option<i64>,
    #[serde(default = "default_baz")]
    pub baz: i64,
}

fn default_baz()-> i64{
    3
}

fn main(){
    let data = r#"{"bar": null, "baz": 1}"#;
    let v: Foo = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", v);
    
    let s = serde_json::to_string(&v).unwrap();
    println!("Don't serialize None values: {:#?}", s);
    
    let data = r#"{"missing_bar": null}"#;
    let v: Foo = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", v)
    
}
```